# Is my calculation of 1x Cubic meter of Top Soil correct?

Tags: soil, grading

I have a 366cm * 366cm round above-ground plastic pool - but the yard runs at a downhill slope.

I want to lay down soil (the grass must grow back when we remove the soil)
so as to level the 366cm * 366cm area. I tried to indicate the slope in the picture, it is at a maximum at the back end about 1x Brick height (8cm)

My calculation 
Volume = 3.66×3.66×0.08 = 1.071648 meter3

Questions:
Are my calculations correct? Will 1m cubic soil be enough for just the pool?
Should I get topsoil only?

[image]

Comment: if you're mainly laying the soil down to level the yard for a pool, do you necessarily need soil? You mention wanting the grass to grow back when you remove the soil, but if you set a pool over the grass for even just a month the grass directly beneath the pool is going to be dead regardless of what you put on top of it. Did you mean you want to have an easy time re-seeding if you remove the pool?

Comment: hi, ok i went the topsoil route, i put down one cubic meter so far. I hope that the grass will grow through the topsoil again when I remove the pool in 4 months

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Whatever you order will be delivered fluffed up in volume. After it compacts you could loose twenty to thirty percent by volume depending on soil type.

Also, soil would be my last choice to level an area that is going to have something heavy on top. Soil is

- easily washed away.
- easy for critters to burrow under
- absorbs water.

You already have a slope where the pool is going.  Where will rain water go now?

I would rather do a long lasting job now than a short term fix so I recommend

- read the manufacturer's recommendations for installation
- excavate the high area where the pool will go so you have a level base.
- order two cubic meters of sand.
- place in layers and compact as you go with a compactor or even a sod roller
- Options are to put synthetic foam board on top of the area
- on the higher side of the pool dig a trench about six inches deep that can take run off somewhere.  Four inch drain pipe with sleeve will do a nice job.
- Please see this answer [here](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/27391/how-can-i-prevent-an-above-ground-pool-underlayment-from-failing-due-to-erosion) for more details on installing pools